# Why do my fitted values from ordisurf not match actual variable values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan, multi-dimensional-scaling

Here is my matrix for the NMDS ordination (PA.mm.5p.rel).

```
structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), .Dim = c(45L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("3", 
"4", "5", "7", "8", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16", "18", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", 
"41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51"
), c("Onisimus", "Amphipods", "Krill", "Copepods", "Fish", "Gammarus", 
"Arctic.cod", "Sand.Lance")))
```

Here is my environmental/individual data (PA_Info).

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 25L), .Label = c("2017-07-19", 
"2017-07-25", "2017-08-07", "2017-08-08", "2017-08-09", "2017-08-12", 
"2017-08-14", "2017-08-15", "2017-08-22", "2017-09-01", "2017-09-04", 
"2018-07-20", "2018-07-23", "2018-07-26", "2018-07-29", "2018-07-30", 
"2018-08-01", "2018-08-02", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-06", "2018-08-08", 
"2018-08-14", "2018-08-19", "2018-08-20", "2018-08-28", "2019-08-08", 
"2019-08-10", "2019-08-11", "2019-08-12", "2019-08-13", "2019-08-14"
), class = "factor"), Floy = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2019L, 
2014L, NA, 2060L, NA, 2575L, NA), FishID = structure(c(16L, 15L, 
25L, 21L, 23L, 22L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 24L, 28L, 26L, 29L, 27L, 30L, 
8L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 10L, 3L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 53L), .Label = c("Char 08", "Char 09", "Char 112", 
"Char 116", "Char 121", "Char 123", "Char 126", "Char 129", "Char 130", 
"Char 132", "Char 138", "Char 150", "Char 154", "Char 156", "Char 54", 
"Char 56", "Char 58", "Char 60", "Char 61", "Char 62", "Char 63", 
"Char 65", "Char 66", "Char 68", "Char 69", "Char 86", "Char 87", 
"Char 88", "Char 89", "Char 90", "SSS001", "SSS002", "SSS003", 
"SSS004", "SSS005", "SSS006", "SSS007", "SSS008", "SSS009", "SSS010", 
"SSS011", "SSS012", "SSS013", "SSS014", "SSS015", "SSS016", "SSS017A", 
"SSS017B", "SSS018", "SSS019", "SSS020", "SSS021", "SSS022", 
"SSS23", "SSS24", "SSS25", "SSS26", "SSS27", "SSS28", "SSS29", 
"SSS30", "SSS31", "SSS32", "SSS33", "SSS34", "SSS35", "SSS36", 
"SSS37", "SSS38", "SSS39", "SSS40", "SSS41", "SSS42", "SSS43", 
"SSS44", "SSS45", "SSS46", "SSS47", "SSS48", "SSS49", "SSS50", 
"SSS51", "SSS52", "SSS53", "TCH01", "TCH02", "TCH03", "TCH04", 
"TCH05", "TCH06", "TCH07"), class = "factor"), TL = c(71, 33.2, 
35.5, 59.5, 53.7, 65.3, 54.5, 57.5, 61.5, 60, 56.5, 53.5, 55, 
57, 61, 38.5, 65.2, NA, NA, 59, 29.5, 17, 79.5, 81.3, 90, NA, 
67, 73.2, 86, 85, 63.2, 72.4, 65.4, 66.8, 67, 59, 63.2, 79, 75, 
90.8, 76, 41.4, 82, 83, 77.6), FL = structure(c(55L, 6L, 7L, 
25L, 16L, 40L, 19L, 22L, 31L, 27L, 21L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 29L, 8L, 
43L, NA, NA, 25L, 5L, 3L, 67L, 72L, 63L, NA, 44L, 57L, 62L, 71L, 
35L, 53L, 45L, 47L, 42L, 24L, 39L, 65L, 60L, 73L, 61L, 9L, 69L, 
70L, 62L), .Label = c("13.5", "15.8", "16", "16.5", "28.3", "31.5", 
"34.5", "38", "39.4", "40.6", "42", "44", "46.8", "48.6", "50", 
"51.5", "52", "53", "53.2", "53.5", "55.4", "56", "57", "57.2", 
"57.5", "58", "58.3", "58.4", "58.8", "59", "59.2", "59.6", "60", 
"61", "61.1", "61.2", "61.4", "61.8", "62", "62.5", "62.6", "63", 
"63.5", "64", "65", "65.4", "65.6", "66", "66.4", "66.8", "67", 
"67.6", "68", "69", "69.9", "70", "70.1", "70.4", "72.6", "72.8", 
"75", "76", "76 (pcl)", "76.4", "76.8", "77.4", "77.5", "78", 
"79.8", "81.4", "83", "83.8", "89.8"), class = "factor"), Girth = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 29, NA, NA, NA, NA, 32.4, 
31, 30, NA, NA, 31, 36, 38.6, 43, NA, 20.6, 37, 46, 35.4), Mass = c(3400, 
8.2, 450, 1800, 1500, 2900, 1300, 1300, 2100, 1900, 1650, 1450, 
1625, 1600, 1850, 550, 2700, 3600, NA, 1300, 237.2, 41.2, 4850, 
5100, 6000, NA, 2350, 2700, 4550, 5600, 1750, 2400, 2020, 1800, 
NA, 1940, 2250, 4000, 3720, 5550, 3150, 620, 4350, 6600, 3900
), Sex = structure(c(5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, NA, NA, 
NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("F", "F?", "I", "J", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2017", "2018"), class = "factor"), 
    MassCat = c("Medium", "Small", "Small", "Medium", "Small", 
    "Medium", "Small", "Small", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
    "Small", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Small", "Medium", 
    "Medium", NA, "Small", "Small", "Small", "Large", "Large", 
    "Large", NA, "Medium", "Medium", "Large", "Large", "Medium", 
    "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", NA, "Medium", "Medium", "Large", 
    "Large", "Large", "Medium", "Small", "Large", "Large", "Large"
    ), Datect = structure(c(1502078400, 1502078400, 1502251200, 
    1502251200, 1502251200, 1502251200, 1502251200, 1502251200, 
    1502251200, 1502251200, 1502510400, 1502510400, 1502510400, 
    1502510400, 1502510400, 1502683200, 1502683200, 1502683200, 
    1502683200, 1502683200, 1502683200, 1502769600, 1503374400, 
    1504238400, 1532059200, 1532577600, 1532836800, 1532923200, 
    1532923200, 1532923200, 1532923200, 1533096000, 1533182400, 
    1533182400, 1533355200, 1533355200, 1533355200, 1533528000, 
    1533528000, 1533528000, 1533700800, 1533700800, 1534219200, 
    1534651200, 1535428800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    week = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("29", "30", "31", "32", "33", 
    "34", "35"), class = "factor"), yday = c(219, 219, 221, 221, 
    221, 221, 221, 221, 221, 221, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 226, 
    226, 226, 226, 226, 226, 227, 234, 244, 201, 207, 210, 211, 
    211, 211, 211, 213, 214, 214, 216, 216, 216, 218, 218, 218, 
    220, 220, 226, 231, 240)), row.names = c(10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 38L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Creating the NMDS and a dataframe of the points.

```
PA.mm.5p.rel.nmds2<- metaMDS(PA.mm.5p.rel, distance="bray", k = 2, autotransform=FALSE)

allNMDS_DF<-as.data.frame(PA.mm.5p.rel.nmds2$points)
```

Running an ordisurf and using a function to extract x, y, and z coordinates from the sp.sf object.

```
sp.sf <- ordisurf(PA.mm.5p.rel.nmds2 ~ PA_Info$TL)

extract.xyz <- function(obj) {
  xy <- expand.grid(x = obj$grid$x, y = obj$grid$y)
  xyz <- cbind(xy, c(obj$grid$z))
  names(xyz) <- c("x", "y", "z")
  return(xyz)
}
```

This is where I extract the coordinates, however the z values in contour.vals do not match the range of values observed in `PA_Info$TL`. You can also see this within the legend when you plot and compare the scales in "level" to "total length". Because there are differences I'm worried that I cannot trust this output from the ordisurf or the related p-value (`summary(sp.sf)`). Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

```
contour.vals <- extract.xyz(obj = sp.sf, plot = F)
head(contour.vals)
contour.vals <- na.omit(contour.vals)

allNMDS_DFTL <- allNMDS_DF[which(!is.na(PA_Info$TL)),]

p <- ggplot(data = contour.vals, aes(x, y, z = z)) + stat_contour(aes(colour = ..level..)) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-2, 2), ylim = c(-1, 1.5)) + theme_bw()+
  geom_point(data = allNMDS_DFTL, aes(MDS1, MDS2, z = 0, shape = PA_Info$Year[which(!is.na(PA_Info$TL))], fill = PA_Info$TL[which(!is.na(PA_Info$TL))]), size=8,shape=21)+
  labs(fill = 'Total Length (cm)') + xlab("Axis 1 (38.2%)")+ylab("Axis 2 (27.9%)")
```

Comment: I don't think anything has gone wrong. Ordisurf is fitting a GAM You would expect the fitted values to have a smaller range (unless you extrapolate or overfit) than the observed response as in any regression model

Comment: @RichardTelford But by that much? The range of my TL values are 17-90 while contour values are only 56-70

Comment: If you run `summary(sp.sf)` you will see that the model has an R2adj of 0.2. If the model had a higher R2, the ranges would become more similar. Also note ranges are sensitive to extreme values in the observed values, so will look worse.